# How do I set environment variables in a python script using a dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, syntax, environment-variables, containers

I'm trying to run a simple hello world program from a docker container. What I want to do is display a custom message that I pass to the environment variable. If nothing is passed to the environment variable than the program should just display a default message of "Hello World!". I've already created an environment variable in my dockerfile and I'm trying to override that variable in my environment variable file using the --env-file flag. However, I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be for setting the environment variable since I'm getting "invalid syntax".

Below are my files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD main.py /
ENV MESSAGE "Hello World!"
CMD ["python3", "./main.py"]
```

env_file

```
MESSAGE="Goodbye World!"
```

main.py

```
# simple hello world program
print($MESSAGE)
```

This is how I'm building and running my container

```
docker build -t example -f Dockerfile .
docker run --env-file=env_file --rm --name example example
```

Comment: please post the full traceback.  though I suspect it's complaining about ```$MESSAGE``` (which, afaik, isn't valid python syntax) .

Comment: if you need to get the environment variable, you need to ```import os``` and then do ```print(os.environ.get("MESSAGE"))```.

Comment: In addition to the other comments and the accepted answer I can't help but wonder why you didn't try running your program on your local workstation/server. Had you done so you would have realized your Python program was syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `main.py` to:

```
import os

print(os.environ['MESSAGE'])
```

Accessing environment variables using `$` in Python is not supported and is not valid Python syntax.

Note that this will raise an exception if there's no such environment variable, so you may want to use `os.environ.get('MESSAGE')` and check for `None` or do some error handling in that case.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you so much!